# SPI - SCLK stuck in mid transmission

Tags: c, fpga, spi, imx8

Context:

An SPI bus is being used to communicate the iMX8 with an FPGA. After some configuration commands, the FPGA begins to fill a memory. When this memory is full, the iMX8 is notified and sends a command to read data from the FPGA. At that point, the FPGA should start sending the data.

The problem:

The problem is that, in the middle of the transmission (while the CS is LOW), the SCLK gets stuck in HIGH and the transmission is extended by "x" microseconds/milliseconds (sometimes more, sometimes less).
[image]

Different transmissions get stuck different amount of time.
[image]

Does someone know where can be this problem coming from? Can it be some issue with the SPI buffers?

I use `spi_ioc_transfer` struct in order to sends commands from the iMX8 to the FPGA via `ioctl` system call.

```
int transfer16(int fd, uint16_t *tx, uint16_t *rx, uint32_t len)
{
    int ret;
    errno=0;

    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (__u64)tx,
        .rx_buf = (__u64)rx,
        .len = len,
        .delay_usecs = 1,
        .speed_hz = spi_speed,
        .bits_per_word = 16,
    };

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret< 0){
        printf("SPI IOCTL ret(%d), error(%d) %s\n", ret, errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: SPI SCLK is driven by the master. So you can't do too much to avoid it as you call the master SPI driver using ioctl

Comment: Any idea what might be causing the issue? Could it be avoided if I made my own driver for the SPI?

Comment: This question is better suited at EE.stackexchange.

Comment: I will ask there then

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the iMX can't receive data at the full SPI speed, possibly because its CPU is overloaded. You'll have to dig into the SPI driver to see what's going on.